# Errors when using the C# 7.0 Tuple in a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tuples, c#-7.0

I am trying the new Tuple syntax in C# 7.0 using the code below and it's not compiling. VS 2017 15.7 .Net 4.6 doesn't give an error count but shows the errors in the output window. Resharper doesn't indicate any errors. The same code runs in Linqpad. I installed `Install-Package System.ValueTuple -Version 4.5.0`.
 What am I missing?

```
private (bool a, bool b) Get(int num)
{
    return (true, false);
}
```

The errors are:

```
error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS1001: Identifier expected
error CS1002: ; expected
Syntax error, ',' expected
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS1520: Method must have a return type
error CS1026: ) expected
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS1513: } expected
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS1513: } expected
```

Comment: Silly question - Have you checked your build settings on all projects to validate you're using the latest C#? Resharper's update language tool didn't work at all for me so maybe it screwed your solution too if you used it.

Comment: Probably doesn't help but it works for me.  You might try restarting VS, sometimes it gets "confused".  I'm running VS 15.7.2

Comment: Same can happen to the new enum constraint. You can compile but the error window can get stuck and you typically want to reopen your project.

Comment: it should compile anyway, clean your solution could help

Comment: When you say "in the output window" - when you compile, or when you run? If this code is in a Razor view for example, that could be very important for the question. Please provide more context. (You shouldn't need to install an extra NuGet package if you're just compiling in a normal way - if any compilation is done at execution time, that's a different matter.)

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, that would be even better - can you reproduce it in a tiny console app?

Comment: The errors that are produced indicate that an older C# compiler (pre-7.0) is being used. It does not recognize the tuple syntax at all...

Comment: @JulienCouvreur: Indeed - which suggests to me that it's compilation which is happening at execution time (or through some other channel). Just using VS2017 at all should allow tuple code in general, right? It might be interesting for the OP to try using another C# 7 feature to see if they observe the same thing.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton. The code was in a web project but it was in a regular .cs file. I am not using Razor. The errors occurred during compilation. I don't know why upgrading the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package fixed it and why I needed it in the first place. Maybe because I had an older version of it, VS is using it instead of its own internal compiler? I don't know. I am notfamiliar with VS's internals.

Comment: "Maybe because I had an older version of it" - do you mean you already had a reference to `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` in your project? Have you tried just *removing* that rather than updating it? That would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the latest version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers which upgraded the version I had fixed the issue but then I went ahead and removed all references to it in the csproj and packages.config files. I can't remember why I needed it.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.8.2
```

Comment: This would be a useful answer with more context in the question, but at the moment I suspect it could be misleading to some people. I strongly suspect that your project is trying to compile that code at *execution time*, but we can't tell as we don't have much context.

Comment: All I did is added a new method and it didn't compile and I posted a question with my configuration. What more of a context are you looking for? What is misleading about my question?

Comment: I'm asking what kind of application you're writing, and where the code was. There's a huge difference between code that appears in a Razor page or view (and will be compiled at execution time unless you precompile your views) and code that appears in the "regular" code of an app that's compiled immediately. I apologise for not being clear on my use of the word "misleading" - I didn't intend to imply that you were *deliberately* misleading people; my point is that other people with a *similar* problem in a different context may get the wrong idea.

Comment: I don't know why the OP got downvoted? I experienced the exact same thing (including the "silent" errors only visible on the "Output" tab). Looking at the code sample, I guess _most_ people would assume it's compile-time compilation of a .cs file, as opposed to runtime compilation of a Razor view.

Comment: Removing the package, as suggested, may not be an option depending on Razor compilation configuration.

Answer (score -1):

After updating Visual Studio version, in order to use the new syntax, you need to do one more thing:

Go to your NUGET package manager and add a reference to `System.ValueTuple.dll`.